# Implementing the AES key schedule

Tags: c++, aes

I'm currently implementing AES in C++, however I've run into a problem with the key expansion portion of the algorithm. My function takes the 128 bit key as one argument and places the expanded key in the array passed as the second argument:

```
void Expand(const unsigned char input[16], unsigned char output[16*11])
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;
    unsigned int t;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        output[i] = input[i];
    }
    for(i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        j = i*16;
        cout << std::dec << i << ", " << j << endl;
        t = *(unsigned int*)(output + j - sizeof(unsigned int));

        //Key schedule core

        cout << std::hex << "0x" << t << " ";
        t = (t >> 8) | (t << 24);
        cout << "0x" << t << " ";
        ((unsigned char*) &t)[0] = sbox[((unsigned char*) &t)[0]];
        ((unsigned char*) &t)[1] = sbox[((unsigned char*) &t)[1]];
        ((unsigned char*) &t)[2] = sbox[((unsigned char*) &t)[2]];
        ((unsigned char*) &t)[3] = sbox[((unsigned char*) &t)[3]];
        ((unsigned char*) &t)[0] ^= rcon[i];

        cout << "0x" << t << " ";

        //First column of current round key
        t ^= *(unsigned int*)(output + j - 4*sizeof(unsigned int));
        *(unsigned int*)(output + j) = t;

        cout << "0x" << t << " ";

        //Second column of current round key
        t ^= *(unsigned int*)(output + j - 3*sizeof(unsigned int));
        *(unsigned int*)(output + j + 1*sizeof(unsigned int)) = t;

        cout << "0x" << t << " ";

        //Third column of current round key
        t ^= *((unsigned int*)output + j - 2*sizeof(unsigned int));
        *(unsigned int*)(output + j + 2*sizeof(unsigned int)) = t;

        cout << "0x" << t << " ";

        //Fourth column of current round key
        t ^= *(unsigned int*)(output + j - 1*sizeof(unsigned int));
        *(unsigned int*)(output + j + 3*sizeof(unsigned int)) = t;

        cout << "0x" << t << endl;
    }
}
```

I've been using the [description on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule) to guide me through the algorithm itself. However, I've been having an odd problem with it that I can't seem to track down: the first 24 bytes in the output are correct (including the 16 from the original key), but then everything else after the 24 byte mark is incorrect. I've been using the key expansion "test vectors" on [this page](http://www.samiam.org/key-schedule.html). I'm probably glancing over some stupid mistake, but I can't spot it. Any help is appreciated.
(BTW the text output in the function was just there for debugging)

EDIT:
So I got my function working by totally rewriting the second loop to be more explicit:

```
    j = i*16;

    t[0] = sbox[output[j-3]] ^ rcon[i];
    t[1] = sbox[output[j-2]];
    t[2] = sbox[output[j-1]];
    t[3] = sbox[output[j-4]];

    output[j] = output[j-16] ^ t[0];
    output[j+1] = output[j-15] ^ t[1];
    output[j+2] = output[j-14] ^ t[2];
    output[j+3] = output[j-13] ^ t[3];

    output[j+4] = output[j-12] ^ output[j];
    output[j+5] = output[j-11] ^ output[j+1];
    output[j+6] = output[j-10] ^ output[j+2];
    output[j+7] = output[j-9] ^ output[j+3];

    output[j+8] = output[j-8] ^ output[j+4];
    output[j+9] = output[j-7] ^ output[j+5];
    output[j+10] = output[j-6] ^ output[j+6];
    output[j+11] = output[j-5] ^ output[j+7];

    output[j+12] = output[j-4] ^ output[j+8];
    output[j+13] = output[j-3] ^ output[j+9];
    output[j+14] = output[j-2] ^ output[j+10];
    output[j+15] = output[j-1] ^ output[j+11];
```

Where t is a size 4 array of unsigned chars. However, I still can't seem to understand why my other code is incorrect. Any suggestions?